# Using two if statements

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

```
@echo off
set Hint=3
echo Hints=%Hint%
pause >nul
set /p Talk=">"
if %Talk%"=="Hint?" &if %Hint%"=="3" echo yay!
pause >nul
cls
```

How do I make it say "yay!" using the two if statements (if you can) and only if %Hint%=3?
I am new to batch and are only a beginner.

Comment: A quick search = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711615/using-multiple-if-statements-in-a-batch-file

Comment: That helped out, thanks Nick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the ampersand `&`  and add double quotes:

```
if "%Talk%"=="Hint?" if "%Hint%"=="3" echo yay!
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the ampersand from your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
if "%Talk%"=="Hint?" (
   if "%Hint%"=="3" (
       echo yay!
   )
)
```

You're also missing some `"`'s

Answer (score 1):

There are no binary logical operators in batch/CMD. You can chain them together, just like you would in C, though.

```
if "%Talk%"=="Hint?" if "%Hint%"=="3" echo yay!
```

If you needed more complex logic, you could use the bitwise AND (`&`) and OR (`|`) operators with `SET /A` to build a more complex expression and reduce it to a single "boolean" integer.